Importing sqlalchemy declarative_base from models into alembic env.py problem
I have a module named models where I placed my database models created with SQLAlchemy. I stored declarative_base into Base (app/db.py), then imported it into the module files like user.py, products.py, and others. After initializing Alembic and upgrading, I noticed that the database foreign keys are not working, and SQLAlchemy can't map them. I think the problem is that I misconfigured the Alembic env.py where I imported Base from db.py to set target_metadata.

this the project structure

enter image description here

and this is inside of the alembic/env.py

from models import product, user, article, tag, order
from db import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata

